# mininet dpctl mod-port in python

Tags: python, openflow, mininet

I can't get dpctl mod-port working on one switch. I defined as a
designated port 6634 with net = Mininet( ..., listenPort=6634) and i
have a topology of 6 switches.
"dpctl mod-port 1 up" works in the mininet console but acts on all
switches.
What i really want is using the dpctl-function of the switch-class.
What would be the cmd?, I tried:

```
switch.dpctl("mod-port tcp:10.0.0.3:6634 1 up")
```

where 10.0.0.3 is the switch IP --> too much arguments, the definition is however "mod-port switch netdev action" which has three operators.

if i don't explicitly integrate the switch identifier (again - since i already call the switch's dpctl-function), i get:

`switch.dpctl("mod-port 1 up")` --> "ovs-ofctl: 1 is not a bridge or
a socket"

so how should i define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch.dpctl('mod-port', <portName>, 'up')
```